# Integrate Blockchain Payment Gateway

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency

I am working with blockchain apis with Exodus, and blockchain is providing feature to generate new wallet address (for e.g. -BTC) which is useful to hide original BTC address from users and it has limit of 20 unused addresses. If 20 generated address are not used by users then after 20 it won't allow to create new address. **[This means at a same time only 20 users can  work and generate address]** to overcome this issue , https://www.blockchain.com/api/api_receive mentioned that ". If you encounter this error, you will either need to switch to a new xPub **(within the same wallet is fine)**, or receive a payment to one of the previous 20 created addresses"

***My questions are:***

1) For e.g. BTC exodus original address is **XXX**

Is there any way/algorithm to "generate random" address **[for e.g. XX1,XX2]** by using XPUB key of exodus wallet and if I pay to XX1 or XX2 amount will basically go to "XXX" ? like blockchain.com is doing ?

2) Any way to overcome issue/limitation of 20 unused address of blockchain.com ?
for example create our own node and generating address ?, if Yes then if you have any solution API which work with PHP, nodejs? Please provide URL for same.

Thank you in advance

Let me know if you have any queries/questions regarding same.

Regards,
Brijal

Answer (score 0):

You can generate as many addresses as you like with the blockchain.com API, by increasing the `gap_limit` parameter.

You can set it to 500 if you like.

However, you will need a way to scan and retrieve funds that are sent to those addresses. Exodus is not a good solution for this, since it only scans past 5 unused addresses.

It's not practical or useful to keep generating and scanning addresses forever. In normal circumstances, Exodus only generates new addresses once existing ones are used, so there is no downside to stopping after 5 empty addresses.

Using a more technical wallet would work better for generating and managing XPubs and addresses.
http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/merchant.html

However, you would still need to more or less build a crypto payment solution from scratch.

There must be ready-made libraries for this, though be careful to pick one that is trusted.